# Redraw overlay on mapview only *after* moving or zooming

Tags: android, android-mapview

### What I want

The same behaviour as the traffic layer in google maps.
It show an overlay and if you move the map you can still see the overlay while moving (the same accounts for zooming) only when you release the screen the rest of the layer is loaded

How can I achieve this?